# sys.excepthook is missing, lost sys.stderr

Tags: python, exception, stderr, ioerror

I have below snippet of code.

```
def do_scheme():
    print """
            <scheme>
            <title>ABC</title>
            <description>ABC is Company</description>
    """
if __name__ == "__main__":
   do_scheme()
```

When I executing this CLI with any other commands like: "python test.py | echo $PATH" or "python test.py | cd..", it shows below error message:

```
close failed in file object destructor:
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr
```

I have tried to handle sys.excepthook but it didn't work. Is there any decorator we can use here to avoid such error message?